# php - script to fix folder structure

Tags: php, io, directory

I am changing the way I save files on the back-end of my website from:

```
uploads/item/x/subitem/y/document.pdf
```

Where x and y are integer id's, changing it to:

```
uploads/item/x/subitem/y/report/document.pdf
```

I need to change the current folder directory as well, which is over 1000 records. Is there a nice way to fix this structure in php without addressing each folder in nested loops, I just need to add another folder before the document.

**EDIT:**

This was the command I was trying to find!

```
foreach(glob('uploads/item/*/subitem/*/*') as $filePath)
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a folder `report/` under `y/` and then move all files in `y/` into `report/`? This doesn't require PHP at all.

EDIT: My bash is very rusty so there are probably a lot of syntax errors in here. But this is the basic idea:

```
for x in /fullpath/uploads/item/*
do
    for y in uploads/item/$x/subitem/*
    do
        cd /fullpath/uploads/item/$x/subitem/$y
        mkdir report/
        mv * report/
    done
done
```

Comment: @tskuzzy if I'm correct in understanding, x and y are numbers.

Comment: You cant just cd "uploads/item/x/subitem/y/" when x and y are random integers

Comment: Woops sorry, edited my answer. You still shouldn't have to use PHP to do this.

Comment: Don't have access to a bash terminal, using windows right now.

Comment: I appreciate your help tskuzzy, but I strictly asked for a php solution. I know bash and the windows command line are powerful and could do this alone but php is my strongest language. I updated what I was looking for in the original question, its similar to your batch answer, just in php. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried php's rename:

```
rename("uploads/item/x/subitem/y","uploads/item/x/subitem/y/report");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Change the current directory to the folder containing all your data
chdir('uploads/item/x/subitem/y');

// Attempt to create the report directory if it does not already exist
if ((file_exists('report') && is_dir('report')) || mkdir('report'))
{
    // Move every PDF file in the current directory
    foreach (glob('*.pdf') as $File)
    {
        rename($File, 'report/' . $File);
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'ERROR! Directory could not be created.';
}
```